# Can't understand how to receive value from mapped element

Tags: reactjs

I am getting info about fake users, which are already exist in contract blockchain. Info which I receive, is just an array of string values. I was setting them in state variable and after it, just mapped them all, passed info in component fields and brought it our. The problem is, that I don't know how to receive index of component out of this function. Can't understand, ho to get index of that element on which I use click event.

I tried to just sent and index in function and see through console what it have by click on any component and all time receive just undefined.

// this is main App.js file

```
handleClick = (index) => {  
console.log(index)
};

render() {

const content =
this.state.candidates.map((voter, index) =>
<Content
              key={index}
              id={index + 1}
              name={voter.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + voter.slice(1)}
              handleClick={this.handleClick}
      / >);
```

// candidates - is an array of string elements.

// and this is component

```
function Content(props) {
const { id, name, account, handleClick,  index } = props;
return (
    <div className="content"   onClick={()=> handleClick(index)}>
        <div>{id}< /div>
        <h4>{name}< /h4 >
        <h5>{account}< /h5>
    </div>
  )
}
```

I want to receive the index of element, on which I click.

Comment: It doesn't look like your passing the index value down to the component anywhere as a prop.  Try giving the `<Content>` component a prop of the index value like `index={index}`

Comment: Huh.. Thank's ! Working ))

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it was answered already.
You have two options:

- either calling `this.props.handleClick(id)` from within `Content` Component
- or passing a function in `handleClick` with `index` param inside `map`, like this:

```
{this.state.candidates.map((voter, index) =>
            <Content
              key={index}
              id={index + 1}
              name={voter.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + voter.slice(1)}
              handleClick={()=>this.handleClick(index)}
            />)
};
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to prevent onClick inline functions, you could write like this:

```
function Content(props) {
  const { id, name, account, handleClick, index } = props
  return (
    <div
      id={index} // accessible through "e.target.id"
      className="content"
      onClick={handleClick}
    >
      <div>{id}</div>
      <h4>{name}</h4>
      <h5>{account}</h5>
    </div>
  )
}
```

```
handleClick = e => {  
  console.log(e.target.id) // gives you the index
}

render() {
  const content = this.state.candidates.map((voter, index) => (
    <Content
      key={index}
      index={index} // Don't forget to pass this down as props
      id={index + 1}
      name={voter.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + voter.slice(1)}
      handleClick={this.handleClick} // no inline, just pass reference
    />
  )

  return (
    // ...
    { content } 
    // ...
  )
}
```

Comment: This problem I already solved. I have another one:
I added the checkbox in this component which I still map.. I have 10 components with button which onClick, change the state variable of checking on true or false. Problem, that it set for all elements. Because it an array, it have no id field and field of checked value. Only which I provided directly on component.